# How do I use regex to pick the following price values?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a scenario where I am trying to pick the price values in Rs from strings in Javascript as follows

```
The price was Rs.1000
The price was Rs 1000
The price was Rs.1000 - 5000
The price was Rs.1000 - Rs.5000
The price was Rs.50,000
The price was Rs 1,25,000 - Rs 2,45,000
```

Now obviously, given the input with so much variety in it, its not a good idea to make a single very long cumbersome regex expression.
Currently I have divided this task into 4 parts
Part 1 
// Extracts all Rs.1000 or Rs 1000

```
var regex = new RegExp(/\brs\W*?(\d{1,7})\b(?![,\d])/i)
```

Part 2
//Extracts all Rs.1000 - 2000 or Rs 1000 - Rs 2000 and any combinations of this

```
regex = new RegExp(/\brs\W*?(\d{1,7})\b(?![,\d])\s*?(?:-|to)\s*?(?:\brs\b\W*?)?(\d{1,7})\b(?![,\d])/i)
```

I need to capture the currency values like 1000 and 2000 to store and process it.

A few questions right off the bat, my array in JS has around 3000 items. I am stuck on Part 3 and 4 that involves commas. Is this the right way to go about it.
How do I get the values in 1 stroke where commas are present

This Regex seems to capture both normal numbers and numbers with commas, and since I just want numeric values rather than have anything to do with where the commas are placed, 
\brs\W*?\d.*,?.*\d\b
I am trying to work one step forward on this expression to include 1000 - 2000 types as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you only need the numbers, or also the "Rs" string?

Comment: Try [`\brs\W*?(\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b(?:\s*?(?:-|to)\s*?(?:\brs\b\W*?)?(\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b)?`](https://regex101.com/r/EVPPsr/1)

Comment: How about removing the commas before step 1...then you won't need steps 3 and 4?

Comment: I only need the numbers @raphael75

Comment: @tewathia stripping the string of commas is a tricky process as the statement may contain somehing like "The price of a 3GB RAM, 2 Mhz processor is Rs.1,22,500 - 2,45,000" I will lose the separation in such cases between the RAM and processor stuff out there

Comment: Is there any way to remove commas just between the digits like Rs.1,22,500 should come out as Rs.122500 while the other commas remain unaffected?

Comment: Based on your examples, would the 1st number *always* have a "Rs." before it?

Comment: it can have an Rs. before the number or after the number, this comes from a JSON feed @raphael75

Comment: If you match the numbers, you can replace anything inside them. Does my suggestion work for you? I get `[
  [
    "1000",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "1000",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "1000",
    "5000"
  ],
  [
    "1000",
    "5000"
  ],
  [
    "50000",
    ""
  ],
  [
    "125000",
    "2,45,000"
  ]
]`. See https://jsfiddle.net/4tu3jk8b/

Comment: thanks for the answer @WiktorStribiżew trying it out

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this sentence  shouldnt match The price was dummytestRs 1,25,000 - Rs 2,45,000and it was an error but your regex picks 2,45 from this

Comment: i am strongly considering the approach to replace commas as suggested by someone above, i guess this regex would do the trick rs.\d.*,.*\d

Comment: I do not get the idea behind why  `The price was dummytestRs 1,25,000 - Rs 2,45,000` should not be matched. It is not possible not to match it. That will make the regex *huge*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right but I am slightly worried as the data comes from json and if someone makes a mistake while entering it on the server side, the client price values to be captured will be inconsistent

Comment: Where are those 'The price was Rs' are in txt? Anywhere, just at beginning of each line, mixed with more 'the price was', at the end of line/text...? Is there any pattern?

Comment: well there is a case insensitive rs it seems with a space or a . and then a currency value that may either have commas or no commas, some values have a range like rs 1000 - rs 2000 or rs 1000 to 2000, this comes from a json feed

Comment: Here is the [regex I meant](https://regex101.com/r/EVPPsr/2) and [the JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tu3jk8b/1/)

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my previous fiddle - see [an updated JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4tu3jk8b/3/). The prices with Rs that is a part of a word are matched but not captured, so we omit them.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you very much , it works very well, let me know what is the maximum number of upvotes I can give ya :) You can paste the fiddle as an answer if you want, but just of plain curiosity, do you think such things should be handled by regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex for this task - you have a regular pattern used to find repeated patterns in a plain text, just create the pattern dynamically. There are 2 main blocks, one that will match the prices glued to other words (so that we could skip that text) and the other will capture the prices only in valid contexts.

The [whole regex](https://regex101.com/r/EVPPsr/2) looks ugly and long:

```
/\Brs\W*(?:\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b(?:\s*(?:-|to)\s*(?:\brs\b\W*?)?(?:\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b)?|\brs\W*(\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b(?:\s*(?:-|to)\s*(?:\brs\b\W*?)?(\d{1,7}(?:,\d+)*)\b)?/gi
```

However, it is clear it consists of simple and easily editable building blocks:

- `(\\d{1,7}(?:,\\d+)*)\\b` - the number part
- `rs\\W*${num}(?:\\s*(?:-|to)\\s*(?:\\brs\\b\\W*?)?${num})?` - the price part

NOTE that the capturing groups are made non-capturing with `.replace(/\((?!\?:)/g, '(?:')` further in the RegExp constructor.

See the JS demo:

```js
const num = "(\\d{1,7}(?:,\\d+)*)\\b";
const block = `rs\\W*${num}(?:\\s*(?:-|to)\\s*(?:\\brs\\b\\W*?)?${num})?`;
const regex = RegExp(`\\B${block.replace(/\((?!\?:)/g, '(?:')}|\\b${block}`, 'ig');
const str = `The price was Rs.1000
    The price was Rs 1000
    The price was Rs.1000 - 5000
    The price was Rs.1000 - Rs.5000
    The price was Rs.50,000
    The price was Rs 1,25,000 - Rs 2,45,000
    The price was dummytestRs 1,2665,000 - Rs 2,45,000`;
let m;
let result = [];
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m[2]) {
    result.push([m[1].replace(/,/g, ''), m[2]]);
  } else if (m[1]) {
    result.push([m[1].replace(/,/g, ''), ""]);
  }
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```